# Flow to Look Up multple Account records, copy field from each record to clipboard

Tags: email, visual-workflow, email-template

I am hoping to find a way that I can achieve the following:

Users are composing an email to a client. They are providing information to the client about one or several Accounts which serve as resource referrals for the client. User would search for the Account(s) they want to share. A formula field on the Account called "Snippet" would combine several fields, including Account Name, Phone, Email, Website, Address, etc. Upon selecting the Account(s) to share, the user would be able to either copy and paste the "snippet(s)" for all selected Accounts into the body of the email.

Open to other ideas outside of Flow if anyone has them!

Thanks!

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_templates_landing_page.htm&type=5